# how to use gpio pins in nRF52840 development kit?

Tags: gpio, nrf52

The GPIO pins are like P0.00, P0.01, P1.01, P1.02 and so on. I didnt know how to use this.
I would like to know, how to use the GPIO pins in nRF52840 for simple LED and push button circuit?
It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPIO pins on the nRF52840 development kits are mapped as follows:-

- P0.00 - P0.31 : SIO0 - SIO31
- P1.00 - P1.15 : SIO32 - SIO47

In other words, P0.01 is SIO1, P1.01 is SIO33, P1.02 is SIO34 and so on. The macro mapping can be found in Nordic_SDK/modules/nrfx/hal/nrf_gpio.h (Line 71).